# "'Module' object has no attribute ..." Multiprocessing Error

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am running Windows 7 with Python 2.7.

I am trying to run basic multiprocessing code with the `multiprocessing` module to test usability. I have seen similar errors [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782961/yet-another-confusion-with-multiprocessing-error-module-object-has-no-attribu) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757794/multiprocessing-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-path) but the code below does not have those issues.

When I run the below code (or any code using the `multiprocessing` module) from the Anaconda Command Prompt or Spyder IDE Python Console I receive the below error message.

When I run the code in the Spyder IDE iPython console I do not receive an error but the program never completes and from my `Windows Task Manager` I can see that python is not using any CPU even though Spyder is showing that it is still running (the red square above the console is red).

```
import multiprocessing

def funSquare(num):
    return num ** 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    results = pool.map(funSquare, range(10))
    print(results)

Process PoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'funSquare'
Process PoolWorker-2:
Process PoolWorker-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'funSquare'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'funSquare'
Process PoolWorker-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'funSquare'
Process PoolWorker-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'funSquare'
Process PoolWorker-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'funSquare'
Process PoolWorker-8:
Process PoolWorker-7:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'funSquare'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'funSquare'
Process PoolWorker-9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'funSquare'
Process PoolWorker-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'funSquare'
```

Can someone tell me how to resolve this? Also let me know if more details are needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was running python 3 and the IDE was spyder in anaconda (windows ) and so I too got the error. But after a long day of searching, I got some solution and it helped me to run the same code my windows machine. This website helped me to get the solution:

http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Multiprocessing-Pool-woes-td5047050.html

Since I  was using the python 3, I changed the program a little like this:

```
from types import FunctionType
import marshal

def _applicable(*args, **kwargs):
  name = kwargs['__pw_name']
  code = marshal.loads(kwargs['__pw_code'])
  gbls = globals() #gbls = marshal.loads(kwargs['__pw_gbls'])
  defs = marshal.loads(kwargs['__pw_defs'])
  clsr = marshal.loads(kwargs['__pw_clsr'])
  fdct = marshal.loads(kwargs['__pw_fdct'])
  func = FunctionType(code, gbls, name, defs, clsr)
  func.fdct = fdct
  del kwargs['__pw_name']
  del kwargs['__pw_code']
  del kwargs['__pw_defs']
  del kwargs['__pw_clsr']
  del kwargs['__pw_fdct']
  return func(*args, **kwargs)

def make_applicable(f, *args, **kwargs):
  if not isinstance(f, FunctionType): raise ValueError('argument must be a function')
  kwargs['__pw_name'] = f.__name__  # edited
  kwargs['__pw_code'] = marshal.dumps(f.__code__)   # edited
  kwargs['__pw_defs'] = marshal.dumps(f.__defaults__)  # edited
  kwargs['__pw_clsr'] = marshal.dumps(f.__closure__)  # edited
  kwargs['__pw_fdct'] = marshal.dumps(f.__dict__)   # edited
  return _applicable, args, kwargs

def _mappable(x):
  x,name,code,defs,clsr,fdct = x
  code = marshal.loads(code)
  gbls = globals() #gbls = marshal.loads(gbls)
  defs = marshal.loads(defs)
  clsr = marshal.loads(clsr)
  fdct = marshal.loads(fdct)
  func = FunctionType(code, gbls, name, defs, clsr)
  func.fdct = fdct
  return func(x)

def make_mappable(f, iterable):
  if not isinstance(f, FunctionType): raise ValueError('argument must be a function')
  name = f.__name__    # edited
  code = marshal.dumps(f.__code__)   # edited
  defs = marshal.dumps(f.__defaults__)  # edited
  clsr = marshal.dumps(f.__closure__)  # edited
  fdct = marshal.dumps(f.__dict__)  # edited
  return _mappable, ((i,name,code,defs,clsr,fdct) for i in iterable)
```

After this function , the above problem code is also changed a little like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from poolable import make_applicable, make_mappable

def cube(x):
  return x**3

if __name__ == "__main__":
  pool    = Pool(processes=2)
  results = [pool.apply_async(*make_applicable(cube,x)) for x in range(1,7)]
  print([result.get(timeout=10) for result in results])
```

And I got the output as :

```
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216]
```

I am thinking that this post may be useful for some of the windows users.