# Callable multiprocessing script

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'll use an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757794/multiprocessing-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-path) as my starting point, because I feel it's a pretty easy minimal example, but I'm looking for a general answer to this question. 
I'm used to do multiprocessing in python in such a way, where everything needed for the real work is encapsulated in an `if __name__`... statement like so:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool as ThreadPool
import requests


API_URL = 'http://example.com/api'

def foo(x):
  params={'x': x}
  r = requests.get(API_URL, params=params)
  return r.json()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  pool = ThreadPool(4) # Hint...
  num_iter = [1,2,3,4,5]
  out = pool.map(foo, num_iter)
  print(out)
```

Now, I want to be able to create a function, to be able to start the multiprocessing part from another python script. But as soon as I replace the if statement with (or encapsulate it in) a function definition and try to run that function I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'foo'`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool as ThreadPool
import requests


API_URL = 'http://example.com/api'

def foo(x):
  params={'x': x}
  r = requests.get(API_URL, params=params)
  return r.json()

def main():
  pool = ThreadPool(4) # Hint...
  num_iter = [1,2,3,4,5]
  out = pool.map(foo, num_iter)
  print(out)
```

So my question is, how to correctly encapsulate multiprocessing in such a way, that it can be conveniently called from another module, scripts etc.?

Comment: Can you show the other script file that is starting the processes?

Comment: in the docu: Note Functionality within this package requires that the __main__ module be importable by the children. This is covered in Programming guidelines however it is worth pointing out here. This means that some examples, such as the Pool examples will not work in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: Well. Basically I run the file in the interactive interpreter. I am aware that https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers states the __main__ module has to be importable. But I don't understand how to achieve that.

Comment: @AriGold: Yes, I know that. But how can this be achieved?

Comment: You're over thinking and making this seem harder than it really is. Create a function that does what you want and ***only*** call it directly or indirectly from code protected by an `if __name__ == '__main__':`. Since it will only be called from that code, you could put the function definition inside the clause, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `if __name__=='__main__':` one way or another.

Here's the `mp_test.py` :

```
import multiprocessing
import os

def worker():
    """worker function"""
    print 'Worker'
    return

def main(module_name):
    jobs = []
    print "The multiprocessing function in %s is called from %s" %(os.path.basename(__file__),module_name)
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

Here's the `main.py`:

```
from imsho import *
import os

if __name__ =='__main__':
    main(os.path.basename(__file__))
```

result :

```
The multiprocessing function in mp_test.pyc is called from main.py
Worker
Worker
Worker
Worker
Worker
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed to understand what's going on.